# Perl: find sum and average of specific columns

Tags: perl

I want to calculate the average over all itemsX (where X is a digit) for each row in Perl on windows.

I have file in format:

```
id1 item1 cart1 id2 item2 cart2 id3 item3 cart3
0     11    34    1   22    44   2   44    44
1     44    44    55  66    34   45  55    33
```

Want to find sum of item blocks and their average.
Any help on this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', "files.txt" or die $!;

my $total = 0;
my $count = 0;

while (<$fh>) {
    my ($item1, $item2, ) = split;
    $total += $numbers;
    $count += 1;
}
```

Comment: i am beginner i tried this use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', "files.txt" or die $!;

my $total = 0;
my $count = 0;

while (<$fh>) {

    my ($item1, $item2, ) = split;

    $total += $numbers;
    $count += 1;

}

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: many thanks i have tried but

Comment: problem is that we need only items columns to be summed and find average but its taking each column of a file

Comment: What is the $numbers in you code? From where you are getting this?

Comment: $numbers is also a column name but we need all items column rows to be summed sorry i m naive at this.

Comment: instead of $number it is item3

Comment: Split the line into columns and then grab the ones you need. `while (my $row = <$fh>) { my @cols = split(' ', $line); ... }` Now the number in the 1st column is in `$col[0]`. The one in the 5th column is in `$col[4]`, etc

Comment: Thanks alot Joshua but i need only item columns there are atleast 20 item columns. Any help. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first line of input (the column names), we store the indices of the columns that start with *item*. For each subsequent line, we sum the columns referenced by the array slice derived from `@indices`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(sum);

my @indices;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;

    if ($. == 1) {
        @indices = grep { $fields[$_] =~ /^item/ } 0 .. $#fields;
        next;
    }

    my $sum = sum(@fields[@indices]);
    my $avg = $sum / scalar(@indices);
    printf("Row %d stats: sum=%d, avg=%.2f\n", $., $sum, $avg);
}

__DATA__
id1 item1 cart1 id2 item2 cart2 id3 item3 cart3
0     11    34    1   22    44   2   44    44
1     44    44    55  66    34   45  55    33
```

Output:

```
Row 2 stats: sum=77, avg=25.67
Row 3 stats: sum=165, avg=55.00
```

Comment: @mariakhalid If it works for you and you think it's the best answer, you should accept it rather than posting a "thanks" comment.